# Slow connection to Filemaker Server from other countries

Tags: filemaker

Our company server is located in China and we used Filemaker make own ERP system. In China all our staff is using Filemaker Pro or Go to connect to the server, and of course there is no problem with connection. Latency is about 30-50 ms. 
But all our customers are from Russia or other countries, and they use Filemaker Webdirect. Sometime they even can't see the login layout, also latency is about 1200 or higher, packet loss is about 50%.

I think a problem is China Great Wall Firewall, and i don't know how we can let our customers have a good connection form other countries?

Comment: You can try to have a different server outside of China and serve web contents from there. You would need to sinc data on both servers. There are a few providers offering FileMaker hosting out there. You should be able to find someone in Russia.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with FileMaker? Did you try any standard web technology to check if firewall slows you down. You might have a problem with your FileMaker setup or design of your system.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Might want to try ServerFault.

Comment: @NicolaiKant problem is not a Filemaker. Problem is a Chinese firewall. I tried xml, php to get data from Filemaker database , and it also very very slow. Setup or design is ok, it's not a very complicated and there is no a lot calculated fields.

Comment: @NicolaiKant I should think about sync 2 servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found a good solution. I've implemented RESTfm open source php code that uses Filemaker server php and xml api.
http://restfm.com/

I've tested it to fetch 1000 records with 13 fields in 3 countries. The longest request time was 8000 ms. It's more better than webdirect or connection through FM GO.
Get or post 1 record is even faster and took only 1000 ms.

So right now I use like a PHP web service between my FM server and other apps.
I also wrote 1 app for iOS, so our customers very happy.